# Consequences of disabling SSL2 and SSL3 on our webserver

Tags: tls

Our system is quite old and as a result gets an F grade for SSL from Qualsys SSL because the server supports SSL2 and SSl3.

We have now identified all the browsers people are using. The oldest is IE7.

If we disable SSL2 and SSL3 ensuring TLS 1 on are enabled, will it appear seamless to our customers or will they need to do anything?

Comment: Don't forget in addition to the above, you can add some script to your site to perform browser detection and force redirect to either a browser upgrade page - or a help page describing how to enable TLS (or upgrade!)
If your site is public facing, also be sure to explain the reason for the redirect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IE 7 and above support TLS 1.0 *and* have it enabled by default, so it should work without any impact. Actually, IE 6.0 also supports TLS 1.0, but it is disabled by default.

Of course, some creative users may have gone through their "advanced Internet settings" and *disabled* TLS 1.0, under the obvious reason that "SSL 3.0 is better than TLS 1.0 since 3 is greater than 1". There's no helping some people.

Answer (score 0):

Useful link from before this question was migrated:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Web_browsers